# When connected through router I get slow speeds, but when connected to modem I get full speeds

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, router, internet

Alright, so when I have my network setup like this `modem -> router -> computer`, I get varying speeds. Usually, they are around 4ms ping 150mbps download and 15mbps upload.

When I connect my network like this `modem -> computer` I get a full 1gbps connection both ways.

Windows says that I have a 1Gbps connection.

Here is what I have tried

1. I have tried multiple ethernet cables (the same result with all of them)
2. My ISP (MetroNet) replaced my eero pro router (still happens with the new router)
3. I have tried on different computers (it works fine on them)

**EDIT:** I have gotten the full 1Gpbs speed on this computer before.

Comment: "I have tried on different computers (it works fine on them)"    Try TCP/IP Reset:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: I wonder if your router simply lacks the ability to gabdle the required number of packets per second?

Comment: Windows "1gpbs" connection is to the ethernet, not the internet. How are you actually testing your speeds & what speeds are you actually paying for from your ISP?

Comment: @davidgo other computers get the full 1Gbps connection

Comment: @Tetsujin I am using the speedtest.net app from the windows store. I am paying for 1Gbps/1Gbps.

Comment: @John I ran the commands you put in there, and I still get the same result for the speed tests

Comment: Try a different (USB Ethernet) card for the problem computer. You said other computers have no issues.

Comment: I don't have any other way to connect an ethernet cable to this computer. I also think that it is a software problem because windows says it is a 1Gbps connection.

Comment: If you think this is a software issue that TCP/IP fix does not help, then do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: @John Just reinstalled windows, and the problem is still there. What doesn't make sense is that I can get the full speed, but I'm not through the router. Is it possible that the router is somehow limiting the speeds I can get?

Comment: You did say that other computers have the correct speed.  So given you have now eliminated software (I think), you need to try another Ethernet card.  Get a USB Ethernet card, install that and try it.

Comment: @John I fixed the problem. I have a Circle device by Disney filtering the internet for our kids. Turns out all the internet traffic was going through that. Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: That's good. Lesson for reinstalling Windows (to anyone reading). Reinstall, and check before installing any software. Saves a lot of grief.